# Copying a row in a table to the end of the same table

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a row in a table and paste it to the end of the same table. I am hoping to be able to click on any cell in that row then press a button that I assign a macro to and it will copy the whole row to the next available row. I found a code online but it only copies unhidden cells and I am looking to copy the whole row including hidden columns.

Is this a code I can use to achieve this, please?

```
Sub CopySelectionVisibleRowsEnd()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim mySel As Range
Dim lRow As Long
Dim lRowNew As Long
Dim lRowsAdd As Long
Dim myList As ListObject
Dim myListRows As Long
Dim myListCols As Long

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set mySel = Selection.EntireRow
Set myList = ActiveCell.ListObject
myListRows = myList.Range.Rows.Count
myListCols = myList.Range.Columns.Count
lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

mySel.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
ws.Cells(lRow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll

lRowNew = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
        SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
        LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1
lRowsAdd = lRowNew - lRow

With myList
    .Resize ws.Range(.Range.Resize(myListRows + lRowsAdd, myListCols).Address)
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: are you referring excel or access here? you want to copy your data from one excel rwo to another? or access?

Comment: You asked: *Is this a code I can use to achieve this please?* It is impossible to say without seeing it. Please [edit] your question and add the code you are using.

Comment: I'd like to see that code, too - I'm not sure how you only select the unhidden cells!  When you manually select a range with hidden columns, the selection still includes the hidden ones; copy the manually-selected range, and the hidden cells go along on the copy.   So I'm interested to see how your bit of code avoids that!

Comment: Sorry it should have said - is THERE (not this) a code I can use to achieve this. I am very new to codes etc so I expect what I have asked is very unclear and what i have been using is probably not correct!  I have been using the code that I have now added to my original question which was working fine until I hid some columns on my table and now it is only copying the unhidden cells? thank you all for taking the time to read and reply to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code only copies the unhidden cells because of this one line:

```
mySel.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
```

If it were just "mySel.Copy",it would copy the whole range.

I'm not going to do forensics on uncommented code with no idea of what data it was intended for, but this code seems to be doing a lot more than you're mentioning - it's searching for the asterisk (*) character to find the ends of the table.   If you just want to do what you said - copy a row to the bottom of the "CurrentRegion" around the cell selected - the code could be a lot simpler.

ASSUMING that you see the table you want to add to, selected when you hit CTRL-* manually after clicking inside the row you want, it's very easy.  CTRL-* selects the "current region", basically all the cells you could "walk to" from your cell without stepping on a blank cell.  In a simple table surrounded by blank rows and columns, it's the table.   If your table is a more complex thing like a "ListObject" - mentioned in the code you provided - then it's less simple, you have to "resize the range" of that ListObject thing.   Or even if your table has a row of totals at the bottom, and you want to add your row above those totals, then that's more complicated, too.

The Range object that embodies the table is just: `selection.currentregion`

The expression for the first row of that table would then be:

`selection.currentregion.rows(1)`

The row you selected in would be:

`selection.currentregion.rows(selection.row-selection.currentregion.rows(1).row+1)`

I know that last one was ugly, but "rows(N)" returns a range that's the Nth row of the table, whereas "row" returns an integer: the absolute row number in the whole spreadsheet.   So you get what row number of the table you're on by subtracting the absolute row number of row #1 of the table from the row number you just clicked on.  And add one.

The LAST row in that table would be, similarly:

`selection.currentregion.rows(selection.currentregion.rows.count)`

...where the "count" method returns how many rows are in that currentregion.

If all that works for your problem, then your code is actually a single, admittedly long, line:

```
selection.currentregion.rows(selection.row-selection.currentregion.rows(1).row+1).copy  selection.currentregion.rows(selection.currentregion.rows.count).offset(1,0)
```

...and you can make it easier to read by breaking it up and using some well-named variables like:

```
Dim WholeTable as Range, MyRow as Range, LastRow as Range
Dim FirstRowNumber as Integer

Set WholeTable=selection.currentregion
FirstRowNumber=WholeTable.Rows(1).Row
Set MyRow=WholeTable.Rows( Selection.Row - FirstRowNumber +1)
```

Any chance the rest can be an exercise for the student?

Comment: Thank you for your help - I have an accounting cashbook table that if I transfer from one account to another I have to duplicate a row so was trying to find a code whereby if I click on a button it will copy the current row to the next available row in my table - I found the code in my question online and it worked when my columns weren't hidden, as I am very new to coding I didn't really have a clue about what else this code is finding - is there a simpler code you can recommend please? much appreciated.

Comment: It's pretty hard to recommend code without seeing the data - the table where you'd want to duplicate the line at the bottom.   We don't write programs for people, here, but we can provide code fragments or examples that will help a lot.   But I'm reluctant to even do that without seeing the data, so that I don't provide any code that might actually hurt the situation.

Comment: I've modified my answer on the assumption that if you hit CTRL-*, it selects the table you want to add a row to.  Read it again from the word ASSUMING onwards.  If useful, please click on the up-arrow above the zero beside the question so that this can be closed as "answered". Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much that works perfectly. I really appreciate you taking the time to explain as well as providing the code so that I can understand it and hopefully that will help me going forward!

Comment: Do you mind doing one more click on the up-arrow beside the answer, to tell the system the question is answered, please?   It's the only meaningful recognition that volunteers get.